# How to prove the covariance of error in a Kalman filter diverges when the system is not detectable?

Tags: kalman-filter, stability-theory

Consider the following linear system

\begin{align}
x_{t+1} = A x_t + w_t,\\
y_t = C x_t + v_t.
\end{align}

If pair $(A, C)$ is not detectable, then how to prove $\mathrm{Cov}(x_t - \hat{x}_t)$ diverges?

Thanks!

Comment: what are $v_t$ and $w_t$?

Comment: @phdmba7of12 They are additive white Gaussian noises.